# Vertical align list

Tags: html, css, list, navigation, vertical-alignment

I've got a navigation (list) on my site with different `heights` of the list items. I'd like to vertically align the list to the bottom:

[image]

```
<nav class="main-nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Lorem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

.main-nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

.main-nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

.main-nav ul li a {
    padding: 20px;
    background: orange;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

.main-nav ul li.active a {
    padding: 30px 20px;
}
```

Check out my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/20z76x1w/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float` and do not forget to [remove extra space](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20z76x1w/3/)

Comment: @sus Opps!! Sorry, I forgot to align the list to bottom. This is [fixed one](http://jsfiddle.net/20z76x1w/4/)